# How to add "custom function help" to a google spreadsheet. - not the script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

It is possible to add "custom function help" to a google spreadsheet?
i.e. If I type =sum into a spreadsheet cell, I get floating help text,
is there a way to do this with custom functions?

Documentation in google apps script is created using JSDoc http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc
style (JavaDoc like) comments.
as documented here 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries?hl=en#guidelines

it looks like these only work in the script editor. It there a way of adding documentation so it appears on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This capability was added in May 2014, and the previous [Issue 2475](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2475) has been closed.

The [examples given in Google's Documentation](https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/blob/master/date_add_and_subtract/Code.gs#L74) are OK, but you can do more with the jsdoc information than they show.

For example:

```js
/**
 * Return the time that the referenced cell or range was last changed.
 * Initial use shows current time.
 *
 * @param {Sheet3!B32}  reference  Cell or range to monitor.
 * @returns                        The time the reference was last changed.
 * @customfunction
 */
function lastModified( reference ) {
  // Surprise - we don't actually care what has changed!
  return( new Date() );
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I covered this with more detail and examples in [my blog](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/did-you-know-custom-functions-in-google-apps-script/#heading_codecomments).

Comment: I wonder, Mogsdad, do you have any observations on how/whether/if JSDoc applies to "optional arguments" in Google Apps script. FWIW, I'm referencing [JSDoc for showing optional arguments in Google Sheets autocomplete dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54383589/1330560)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that there is no documentation on this, I would assume that this functionality is not possible. Consider [looking for an existing request for this on the Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) and if not, make a feature request! I'm sure you're not the only one who would like to see this.

Comment: Thanks. I did check the issue tracker, did not find anything. So maybe, if I am lucky, there is a way of doing this.

Comment: issue posted by Daniele: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2475

Answer (score 1):

I posted a feature request for that.
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2475