# JSDoc for showing optional arguments in Google Sheets autocomplete dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jsdoc, custom-function

I'd like to document (in the Google Sheet autocomplete) a custom function with optional arguments, similar to the `WEEKDAY` function (autocomplete below).

The [JSDoc spec on optional arguments](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#optional-parameters-and-default-values) does not work. Google does not seem to document this anywhere. How can I create a function with the same visual treatment (both in the argument description and the Example) that Google has?

[image: Google's autocomplete for WEEKDAY]

```
/**
 * Summary of function
 * @param {"example"} arg Argument description
 * @param {"optional"} opt_arg This argument is optional
 * @return {String} Return value description
 * @customfunction
 */
function JSDOC(arg, opt_arg) {
  return
}
```

Generates this autocomplete:

[image: My custom function autocomplete]

This is not [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015373/how-to-add-custom-function-help-to-a-google-spreadsheet-not-the-script-edit). I'm specifically asking about optional arguments, as you can see, I've successfully gotten the autocomplete's other features working.

Comment: I don't think JSDoc works the way you think it does.  It's not an add on to javascript, its an interpreter of your javascript code and generates a document.

Comment: @TheWizEd You misunderstand my question. I'm aware that JSDoc is not a "addon" to javascript. I named the function JSDOC just randomly. I'm looking to understand the syntax that Google Apps Script supports for documenting functions, in particular their optional arguments.

Comment: To be clear, both `=` and `[]` didn't work?

Comment: @ehfeng Is this what you're looking for [Custom Functions in Google Sheets - AutoComplete](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#autocomplete). Mogsdad has an excellent discussion on this in [How to add “custom function help” to a google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31326326/1330560), plus a link to a much detailed blog post.

Comment: @Tedinoz He's specifically looking for arguments to be regarded "optional".

Comment: @TheMaster You're quite right-I deleted the suggestion of a possible duplicate.

Comment: Yes, both `=` and `[]` don't work. I've read through that article as well, and as @TheMaster mentioned, they don't mention optional arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Apps Script doesn't support optional params in their JSDoc at this moment.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: On the Google Custom Functions page they link to the JSDoc. http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html When you look at the spec optional should be = or []. Both doesn't work.

Comment: You should have included this in your answer.

Comment: I was more curious if others had found workarounds. @example isn't supported, but Apps Script lets you overload the type declaration instead.

Comment: @ehfeng, examples are created with {} tags for params

Answer (score 1):

JsDoc isn't fully supported. Specifically  optional parameters isn't supported. A related tracker link is here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156230902

Anyone interested in this issue may add a +1(on the top bar, not as a comment) to this issue. They may also add a new specific [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) for the same.